# Listview on to of an Imageview

Tags: android, listview, imageview

So I created an Imageview and placed it as a background so now I'm trying to put listview on top of the image so it looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVbjA.jpg

I have tried using the solutions from some Stackoverflows questions one of them using the the weight but it doesn't seem to make it work.. Any help would be really appreciated.

Here is my current xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ptr_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#515E71"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_flatcolor"
        android:dividerHeight="1.8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="20px" android:paddingTop="10dip" android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:src="@drawable/background_khabar" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use RelativeLayout if you want to put views on top of eachother. And ImageView should be the first element, since it is the background.

Comment: You want image as List's background?

Comment: I want to put them on top of each other not the image being the background of the listview.

Answer (score 0):

I used Carnal answer which I had to use RelativeLayout and put the XML code of ImageView before the ListView code! Thanks Carnal!